# Generating random numbers using a syscall

Tags: random, int, mips, system-calls, mars-simulator

I'm trying to generate a random integer from 0-99 (inclusive) but I'm having some difficulty finding where it stores the value to when using the 42 syscall.

So far I have:

```
li $a1, 100
li $v0, 42
syscall
```

I'm not sure where the value generated is stored so I can use it though.

Answer (score 2):

From a [syscall](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) help page: `$a0` is the pseudorandom number generator id, `$a1`is the upper bound, and the returned random number will also be contained in `$a0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what pseudorandom refers to though.

Comment: It means "ultimately deterministic, but not easily predictable". Random enough for most purposes.

Comment: So is what I have for the 'random' generation from 0-99 (inclusive) correct? I just need to move the number from $a0 to whatever register I want to use?